# create the for loop to find the string in the variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on my code to create a for loop get the list of strings.

I want to create a loop for the variable `pos_X` so I can use them to find the strings `375` and then get the list of strings from the variable `prog_id` to add them in the list.

Here is the code:

```
program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
progId = list()
posX = list()
posY = list()
prog_id_list = list()
prog_index_list = list()

for elem in program_button:
    progId.append(elem.getId())
    posX.append(elem.getX())
    posY.append(elem.getY())
progId = map(str, progId)
posX = map(str, posX)
posY = map(str, posY)
prog_index_list = [program_index_]


for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_index in izip_longest(posX, posY, progId, program_index_, fillvalue=''):
    print pos_X

    #create a for loop to find the strings 375 with variable pos_X
    prog_id_list += [prog_id]
```

Here is the output for the `pos_X`

```
 ['375', '1073', '1422', '1513', '1604', '1953', '375', '1073', '1422', '1946', '2644', '3342', '375', '1420', '2465', '3163', '5252', '5950', '375', '1073', '1771', '2469', '3167', '3865', '375', '1073', '1771', '3513', '4558', '5256', '5605', '375', '724', '1073', '1771', '2469', '3167', '3865', '375', '1073', '1771', '2469', '3167', '3865', '4563', '5261']
```

I have no idea how I can find the strings `375` in the variable `pos_X` when creating the for loop and I have no idea how to use the string as a index to find the matched strings in the list of `prog_id`.

Can you please tell me how I could do that?

**EDIT:**

When I try this under the for loop:

```
for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_index in izip_longest(posX, posY, progId, program_index_, fillvalue=''):
    if int(pos_X) == 375:
        print prog_id
```

Here is the output for the `prog_id` when I use the `if int(pos_X) == 375:` statement:

```
22:49:15 T:6892  NOTICE: 3003
22:49:15 T:6892  NOTICE: 3131
22:49:15 T:6892  NOTICE: 3259
22:49:15 T:6892  NOTICE: 3387
22:49:15 T:6892  NOTICE: 3515
22:49:15 T:6892  NOTICE: 3643
22:49:15 T:6892  NOTICE: 3771
```

I want to create the for loop for the `pos_X` with the string `375` to allow me to find the ids I want from the strings `prog_id` to add the ids in the list `prog_id_list`.

Comment: Please strip your question of everything that is not needed for the actual problem. Start from scratch, provide a minimal example as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the question makes me dizzy. It's very unclear. Please describe what you want to achieve and provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have the strings `375` that I want to find them in the list `pos_X`, then I want to find the matched string in the list `prog_id` to get the ids and I want to add them in the list `prog_id_list`. How I can do that?

Comment: please edit your question and show us your lists (pun intended). The whole input and desired output

Comment: @user3848630 your explanation is still completely impossible to understand. Read the MCVE article, follow it, or you won't get a qualified answer.

Comment: @Pynchia Ok I have updated. Hope you will understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @timgeb Ok I have updated. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can do something like this:

```
program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
progId = list()
posX = list()
posY = list()
prog_id_list = list()
prog_index_list = list()

for elem in program_button:
    progId.append(elem.getId())
    posX.append(elem.getX())
    posY.append(elem.getY())
progId = map(str, progId)
posX = map(str, posX)
posY = map(str, posY)

for i in range(len(posX)):
    pos_X = posX[i]
    if pos_X == '375':
        prog_id_list.append( progId[i] )
        prog_index_list.append( i )
```

Comment: Do you need to convert all the positions to strings? I recommend removing `posX = map(str, posX)` and `posY = map(str, posY)` and changing `if pos_X == '375':` to `if pos_X == 375:`

Comment: @Wallace thank you very much for this, this is what I really wanted. Much appreicated!

Comment: @user3848630 can you accept this answer as correct please?